# How to obtain the User-Agent property from the installed browser?

Tags: browser, http-headers, user-agent

How to get `User-Agent` property of locally installed browser? For example, for *Internet Explorer* or *Firefox* is there a way to pull the exactly same string as browsers do? Or maybe other question, how browsers form that string? (to do it by analogy by myself)

**UPDATE**

Operating System is `Microsoft Windows`

I'm searching for a clue of local solution without internet services (i.e. something like reading `registry` or examining browser or Windows DLLs, API invocations, etc). Running a browser once to get data from it is also suitable. I need an idea, I don't need a four-pages of WinAPI code :) (I'd like to implement solution on `Python`)

Solutions to go with browser to a certain URL read captured HTTP request aren't good - I can do it by myself, but it is desired to obtain data with minimal user movements and everytime be sure that `User-Angent` is actual as in browser is.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it here: http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/ :) Unfortunately got no idea how browsers form their user-agent string.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no guideline to write the user-agent. Each browser have their own way to generate its user-agent.

Nevertheless, you can observe how are written the user-agent of each browser. They are similar independently the versions. For example for Firefox, this is my user-agent:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0

You can easily define a pattern

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT {WinVersion}; {FirefoxArchitecture}; rv:{FirefoxVersionRevesion}) Gecko/{GeckoVersion} Firefox/{FirefoxVersion}